# Best practice for storing data on MongoDB document

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm storing users stats for a game I work on and I wonder what is the best practice on how to make my data model/schema. I have some user game stats that can be organized in objects but I don't know if it's better to keep these data at the document root or stored in objects.

To be clear I thought about these two options, according to you, what is the pros and cons of these two schemas?

### Every data at doc root

```json
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    played: 12,
    won: 10,
    wonStreakActual: 2,
    wonStreakMax: 6,
    wonLast: "2021-12-28",
    defeat: 2,
    defeatStreakActual: 2,
    defeatStreakMax: 2,
    defeatLast: "2021-12-28"
}
```

### Data stored in objects

```json
{
    _id: <ObjectId>
    played: 12,
    won: 
    {
        total: 10,
        streak: {actual: 2, max: 6}
        last: "2021-12-28"
    },
    defeat: 
    {
        total: 2,
        streak: {actual: 2, max: 2}
        last: "2021-12-28"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The second one will probably look nicer in terms of your app-level models. But other than that, they're the same.

Comment: "if it's better to keep these data at the document root or stored in objects" - as with everything, there's no universal "better". Everything is a trade-off, improves something, but makes something else worse. Storing fields at root level: less prep work needed, you can get the functionality faster (good), but, arguably, will result in messier models that will cost you in maintenance effort/time (bad). And so on.

Comment: I would say, it is more matter of taste which one you use. However, you should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper `Date` objects.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: or unix timestamps, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! @SergioTulentsev it's exactly what you said, it's a trade-off. I think the object way need more work to implement but looks better in term of architecture and maintenance point of view.

Comment: You are right @WernfriedDomscheit, I'll store Date with a proper format, it is just pseudo code for my question :) I don't know if Date is better than Unix timestamp?

Comment: Mongodb provides a native `Date` type, so I would prefer it. It does not make much difference, because internally it stores the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. But you may need to do more conversion

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to put it into it's own objects. You can create simpler filtering.

E.g. with queries:

```
db.query(...).select('won') // gives you only victories.
// vs.
db.query(...).select('won wonStreakActual wonStreakMax wonLast');
```

At this level it's simple. But if you refactor code - add or remove props, rename things - you have to go to every query and check. With a subdocument, you narrowed your scope of change.

Or in application/domain code:

```
someService.calculateVictoryStats(newGame, object.won);
// vs
someService.calculatVictoryStats(newGame, object.won, object.wonStreakActual, /*... more of them*/);;
```

Whoever uses your API - e.g. Angular or React frontend will be happy too. React example

name: {player.name}
     
     ...
   
     
vs this:

```
<PlayerVictories {player.won}> // original version
<PlayerVictories won={player.won} wonStreakActual={player.wonStreakActual} ....>
```

Similar would be with Angular components, say inputs:

```
class PlayerVictoryStats {
  @Input() won: Won; // the whole object at once
  //vs
  @Input() won: number;
  @Input() wonStreakActual: number; 
  @Input() ....
```

And also, think of future changes etc.